# How to execute a spark sql query from a map function (Python)?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

How does one execute spark sql queries from routines that are not the driver portion of the program?

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *


def doWork(rec):
    data = SQLContext.sql("select * from zip_data where STATEFP ='{sfp}' and COUNTYFP = '{cfp}' ".format(sfp=rec[0], cfp=rec[1]))
    for item in data.collect():
        print(item)
    #    do something
    return (rec[0], rec[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="Some app")
    print("Starting some app")

    SQLContext = SQLContext(sc)

    parquetFile = SQLContext.read.parquet("/path/to/data/")
    parquetFile.registerTempTable("zip_data")


    df = SQLContext.sql("select distinct STATEFP,COUNTYFP from zip_data where STATEFP IN ('12') ")
    rslts = df.map(doWork)

    for rslt in rslts.collect():
        print(rslt)
```

In this example I'm attempting to query the same table but would like to query other tables registered in Spark SQL too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One does not execute nested operations on distributed data structure.It is simply not supported in Spark. You have to use `joins`, local (optionally broadcasted) data structures or access external data directly instead.

Answer (score 0):

In case when you can't accomplish your task with the `joins` and want to run the SQL queries in memory:

You can consider using some in-memory database like `H2, Apache Derby` and `Redis` etc. to execute parallel faster SQL queries without loosing benefits of in-memory computation.

In-memory databases will provide faster access as compared to `MySQL, PostgreSQL` etc. databases.